# removing certain values from a ggplot legend created with 2 different geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've made a ggplot graph where the legend is made from mappings from 2 different geoms like this:

```
# Create data.frame with shading info
shading <- data.frame(min = seq(from = 0.5, to = max(as.numeric(as.factor(mtcars$carb))), by = 1),
                      max = seq(from = 1.5, to = max(as.numeric(as.factor(mtcars$carb))) + 0.5, by = 1),
                      col = c(0,1))

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = factor(carb), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_rect(data = shading,
            aes(xmin = min, xmax = max, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                fill = factor(col)), alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "white", "green", "blue", "red")) +
  geom_col(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = factor(carb), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl)))
```

[image]

How can I drop the first 2 legend items (the black 0 and the white 1) from the legend but retain it on the graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly set the breaks in your `scale_fill_manual()` call -- which allows you to say which will be labeled and which will not be labeled. (I left the remaining code untouched here). There's a bit more info and walkthrough if you're looking for that: https://luisdva.github.io/rstats/set-the-breaks/

```r
library(ggplot2)
shading <- data.frame(min = seq(from = 0.5, to = max(as.numeric(as.factor(mtcars$carb))), by = 1),
                      max = seq(from = 1.5, to = max(as.numeric(as.factor(mtcars$carb))) + 0.5, by = 1),
                      col = c(0,1))

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = factor(carb), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_rect(data = shading,
            aes(xmin = min, xmax = max, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                fill = factor(col)), alpha = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "white", "green", "blue", "red"),
                    # Adding breaks
                    breaks = c(4, 6, 8)) +
  geom_col(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = factor(carb), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

One quite straight forward option without messing too much with factor levels is simply using two scales for fill.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)
#> Warning: package 'ggnewscale' was built under R version 4.0.2
shading <- data.frame(min = seq(from = 0.5, to = max(as.numeric(as.factor(mtcars$carb))), by = 1),
                      max = seq(from = 1.5, to = max(as.numeric(as.factor(mtcars$carb))) + 0.5, by = 1),
                      col = c(0,1))

ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = mtcars, mapping = aes(x = factor(carb), y = mpg, fill = factor(cyl)))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c( "green", "blue", "red")) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_rect(data = shading,
            aes(xmin = min, xmax = max, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf,
                fill = factor(col)), alpha = 0.3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("black", "white"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is a good solution if external dependencies are not a problem.